# Clone production cluster

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm new to elasticsearch and would like to know the best way to do this

basically I'm trying to clone a production cluster and then use it for testing
it needs to be a complete copy and should not interrupt the production cluster

I thought about adding a new node to the production cluster and increase the number of replicas then separate that node and rename it as a new cluster

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's one way to do it, though not my personal preference because I wouldn't want to risk mixing test and production concerns, and you'd have the increased number of replicas to deal with after the fact.

You could also use the [Snapshot and Restore APIs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-snapshots.html) to take a snapshot and then restore it into your testing cluster. Just set your test cluster to `readonly` for the repository, then you can take snapshots from production and load them into test at will.